# How do I transfer an image?

Tags: express

I want to transfer an image using express. but it gives me cannot get and it is not displayed. what should I do?

UPD: Structure: The main folder is "public", there is only app.js - server. inside it is the "assets" folder. In the "assets" secret.png and "a.html." Nothing is sent to the network.

```js
let path = require('path');
let express = require('express');
let app = express();

app.use(express.static('public'))
app.use(express.static('secret.png'))


app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.redirect("/assets/a.html");
});



app.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log('Listening on http://localhost:3000/');
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<img src="secret.png">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you add your project structure to the question? Also, can you check the Network tab in the browser Developer tools for the request to load the image?

Comment: I'm not sure how to properly describe it, but I hope everything is normal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the folder structure is

```
public
  assets
    secret.png
    a.html
  app.js
```

In your `app.js` file, you need to serve static files from the `assets` folder. Try this:

```
let path = require('path');
let express = require('express');
let app = express();

app.use(express.static('assets'))

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
   res.sendFile(__dirname + "/assets/a.html"); // fix based on Kony's comment
});

app.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log('Listening on http://localhost:3000/');
});
```

In your `a.html` file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <img src="/secret.png">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks a lot, but it didn't work until I changed it to res.sendFile(__dirname + "/assets/a.html");